# Sending "Set-Cookie" in a Python HTTP server

Tags: python, http, cookies

How do I send the "Set-Cookie" header when working with a `BaseHTTPServerRequestHandler`, and `Cookie`? `BaseCookie` and children don't provide a method to output the value to be passed into `send_header()`, and `*Cookie.output()` does not provide a HTTP line delimiter.

Which `Cookie` class should I be using? Two have survived into Python3, what are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `C = http.cookie.SimpleCookie` to hold the cookies and then `C.output()` to create the headers for it.

[Example here](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/http.cookies.html#example)

The request handler has a `wfile` attribute, which is the socket.

```
req_handler.send_response(200, 'OK')
req_handler.wfile.write(C.output()) # you may need to .encode() the C.output()
req_handler.end_headers()
#write body...
```

Comment: @Tor this sending does not work, SimpleCookie does not output a complete header

Comment: Of course you need to add more headers than just the cookies... I thought that was obvious.

Comment: no, the cookie's output is not valid to write either to `self.wfile` in the handler **OR** to `self.send_header()`

Comment: @Tor. I know the example you've given _looks_ right, but if you actually try it you will see what I'm talking about.

Comment: the example i've given is from the example link above it.. and the general example is taken from the source of BaseHTTPRequestHandler...

Comment: `self.send_header('Set-Cookie', C.output(header=''))` works.

Got it from here.  
http://b.leppoc.net/2010/02/12/simple-webserver-in-python/

Annoying this isn't documented in either the http.server.html or the http.cookies.html python docs..

Comment: It seems since Python 3.3, `send_response()` is writing to a internal buffer, which is sent to the server only when `end_headers()` is called
(see [this note in send_response() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.send_response).
This means you can no longer add a header with `wfile.write`, if other headers are added with `send_response()`. That's the reason why this does not work with Python>=3.3.

Comment: You can also flush the header buffer by using [flush_headers()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.flush_headers).

Answer (score 6):

This sends a Set-Cookie header for every cookie

```
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")

        cookie = http.cookies.SimpleCookie()
        cookie['a_cookie'] = "Cookie_Value"
        cookie['b_cookie'] = "Cookie_Value2"

        for morsel in cookie.values():
            self.send_header("Set-Cookie", morsel.OutputString())

        self.end_headers()
        ...
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Others are incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the code below, which uses `SimpleCookie` 
from [http.cookies](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/http.cookies.html#example) to produce an object for a cookie.
Then, I add a value to it, and finally, I add it to the list of headers
to send (as a `Set-Cookie` field) with the usual `send_header`:

```py
    def do_GET(self):

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")

        cookie = http.cookies.SimpleCookie()
        cookie['a_cookie'] = "Cookie_Value"
        self.send_header("Set-Cookie", cookie.output(header='', sep=''))

        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(PAGE, 'utf-8'))
```

The parameters for `cookie.output` are important:

- `header=''` ensures that no header is added to the string it produces (if not done, it will produce a string that will start with `Set-Cookie:`, which will cause to strings like that in the same header, since `send_header` will  add its own).
- `sep=''` causes no final separator.

Comment: this will work only if there will be only one cookie at one time written